How can I have my floating button appear over other contents in my layout?
So I am trying to build an app in Android Studio using Java. And in my activity_main.xml file I am including a trademark file. I defined my floating button in the trademark.xml file since I will be using it in other layouts as well. But my button seems to not hover over other contents in my layout. Could someone please help me fix it?
Here's the trademark.xml code
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:backgroundTint="#747474"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/happybirthday"
        android:layout_below="@id/fav"
        android:id="@+id/happyBirthday"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"/>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:contentDescription="Music Card"
        android:layout_below="@+id/happyBirthday"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:id="@+id/video"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/videoimage" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/music"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/happyBirthday"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/musical_note" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/video"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/notes"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/notes" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/music"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/resources"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/resources"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notes"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/contacts"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/contacts"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/resources"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/mystery">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/mystery"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    <include layout="@layout/trademark"/>
</RelativeLayout>

Here's how it looks like:
enter image description here
I tried searching in chat gpt but it keeps saying to declare the floating button in my activity_main.xml file. But I am trying to use this button in every layout so I don't want to do that. I want to declare it in the trademark.xml file and keep including it whenever i need it.

There is no mention or procedure for a trademark.xml file in the Android SDK or its documentation. You will need to manually add the trademark to each layout. Alternatively, you can create a TrademarkActivity and have every Activity in your project inherit from it. In the TrademarkActivity, you can programmatically include the trademark in the layout.

@AdilSoomro I know i have to use the  tag but thats not the problem. My problem is that the floating button doesn't hover over my other contents. Can you tell me how to fix that? You can check the picture. You'll understand what I mean.

Typically, the last item in xml layout is always on top in z index, so make sure have the include tag as last item in your xml.

It's still showing the same layout.

Please post full xml layout of any activity.

I posted it now
